# Cocoa: Clicking on "Watch on YouTube" inside a WebView does nothing

Tags: cocoa, webkit, webview, youtube

I hava a `WebView` with an embedded YouTube video in it. The video plays fine and everything about it works except when clicking on "Watch on Youtube".

I'd like the "Watch on YouTube" button to open the YouTube video on the default browser but currently it just doesn't do anything.

I have a `WebPolicyDelegate` set on the `WebView` but neither:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView 
   decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation
        request:(NSURLRequest *)request
          frame:(WebFrame *)frame
decisionListener:(id<WebPolicyDecisionListener>)listener`
```

nor:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView 
decidePolicyForNewWindowAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation
        request:(NSURLRequest *)request
   newFrameName:(NSString *)frameName
decisionListener:(id<WebPolicyDecisionListener>)listener
```

are called when the "Watch on YouTube" button is clicked.

How could I detect that the "Watch on YouTube" button was clicked so I can open it on the default browser?

Answer (score 1):

The "Watch on YouTube" button performs its navigation in a new tab/window, so you'll need to implement `WebUIDelegate`'s `-webView:createWebViewWithRequest:` method. You'll have to infer from the request's URL whether the request was initiated by the "Watch on YouTube" button or not. Once you know that, you can tell the default browser to open the URL and return `nil` from your delegate method to tell WebKit that you're disallowing the navigation.